# Swift - Detect when certain table section comes into view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, viewdidappear

I have a table with 7 sections - only the first 2 sections are visible when it loads.

To simplify things - how would I print "Now at section 5" when the user scrolls and gets to that section?

I have tried all over Google but not getting the results I want. I assume the code should go in ViewDidAppear?

Comment: One of the simplest ways is to check the section in `cellForRowAt` or `willDisplayCellFor`. It depends on what you are trying to do.  If you went to opportunistically load data then you can look at table view prefetch protocol

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I know I should provide more code but I don't really have any in this instance. 

All I am trying to do is simply set a bool to true once the section has been reached.

Comment: You can simply set your `bool` to `true` when you see that section in `willDisplayCellFor` then.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I did try that in this kind of way:

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 5 {
            
            setMyVar = true
            
        }
    }

... but this sets the variable as soon as the page is loaded as well as when I reach that section?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the code from this post in the end:

[Detect UITableViewCells that appear on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415827/detect-uitableviewcells-that-appear-on-the-screen)

Thanks for your help.